# Node JS - SQL Server stream to file strange behavior

Tags: sql-server, node.js, file, stream

I'm trying to write a small agent that runs a query on a SQL Server module 'mssql'.

I try to append every row into a file as JSON format and compress that file.

```
var sql = require('mssql');
const fs = require("fs");
const zlib = require('zlib');
var ini = require('ini');
var config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.ini', 'utf-8'));
var out = fs.createWriteStream('result.txt.gz', {flags: 'a'});
var JSONStream = require( "JSONStream" );
const gzip =  zlib.createGzip();

var transformStream = JSONStream.stringify();

var sqlConfig = {
  user: config.database.user,
  password: config.database.password,
  server: config.database.server,  
  database: config.database.database
};

(async function(){
    console.log("sql connecting......");
    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        const request = new sql.Request()
        request.stream = true 
        request.query(config.database.query) 
        transformStream.pipe(gzip).pipe( out );

        request.on('row', row => {
            transformStream.write(row); 
        })

        request.on('error', err => {
            if (err) throw err;
        })

        request.on('done', result => {
            transformStream.end();
            sql.close();
        })
})

sql.on('error', err => {
    if (err) throw err;
})

})()
```

The query is stored into the .ini file.

The behavior depending on the query I pass is strange : my query with top 1000 takes 0 sec in SSMS and 0 sec using this code => this is normal.

When I use the same query but filtering only on row with date >= yesterday without the top 1000 the query returns 700 lines and takes 50 mins to run.

At the end the file generated is 55mb compressed and more than 1GB uncompressed.
If I run the query in SSMS it takes less than 10 sec

In term of size I shouldn't have 1gb file with 700 lines so there is an issue I'm not able to troubleshoot.

Here are the SQL queries mentioned :

Query A:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 list_of_columns 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE field_A = 'X' AND field_B = 'Y'"
```

Query B:

```
SELECT list_of_columns
FROM TABLE 
WHERE field_A = 'X' 
  AND field_B = 'Y' 
  AND field_date >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE() - 1), 0)
```

First I thought that the issue might comes from the fact that I'm trying to redirect the stream to a file and not a POST request for example and that might be too slow but how comes the query A create my fill with my 1000 rows in less than a second but not with the other query.